# Мой apk файл заблокирован Play защитой

Tags: android, apk

Друзья, прошу помощи! На днях создал apk файл моего приложения в android studio отправил друзьям на тест. Они установили приложение по моему apk файлу без проблем. Потом я сделал доработки и создал новый apk файл отправил на тест, но ни один друг не смог установить приложение. Мой apk файл блокирует Play защита. Если выбираешь "все равно установить" - пишет приложение не установлено. В чем может быть причина? Помогите, пожалуйста!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это окно - просто предупреждение о том, что GP не знает такого разработчика. Скорее всего проблема в самом приложении - подпись другая, в манифесте напартачили, ещё что-то... Вы себе-то пробовали поставить ту же версию из APK?

Comment: Непосредственно запуск на устройстве через android studio работает как надо. но когда себе пробую ставить апк, тоже не разрешает. Значит дело в подписи может быть? Я релиз использовал.

Comment: Удалите то, что стояло, и поставьте снова

Comment: Такой вариант пробовал, несколько раз, ещё ни один апк файл других моих приложений не хочет открывать, все бракует

Comment: А та версия что уже стоит у друзей тем же ключом подписана? Или вы дебажную версию им давали тестировать? Дебажная версия подписывается дебажным ключом, который генерируется при первом запуске студии. APK с таким же пакетом (`aplicationId`) но другой подписью не может обновить существующий, может быть установлен только "на чистую".  Но если вообще никакие не устанавливаются - это уже подозрительно.

Comment: Откройте приложение `Play Market` - там в меню есть плей-защита и по идее должно быть написано какие приложения проверялись и были заблокированы. И скорее всего оно должно было сообщить о таком событии.